# Sending mail with css is not applying in zend

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-mail

I am using zend.Following is my piece of code in my Action

```
.......
 // create view object
                $html = new Zend_View();
                $html->setScriptPath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/layouts/scripts/');
                // assign values                

                $html->assign('OrderList', $this->view->OrderList);
                $html->assign('title', 'Package Slip');
                $html->assign('current_date', date("F d, Y"));

                // render view
                $bodyText = $html->render('test.phtml');  
                $mail = new Zend_Mail('utf-8');
                $mail->setBodyHtml($bodyText)
                ->setFrom('noreply@metalxplus.com', 'admin')
                ->addTo('dineshkumar.m@openwavecomp.in')
                ->setSubject('Test');
                $mail->send(); 
........
```

When I echo this $bodyText variable before sending mail, I got complete page with css. But when i send it to mail, css is not applying. What i have to do here? Kindly advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many email clients utilise old version of html and therefore do not respect css. Gmail for instance will not respect any css you add to your message.

To view output, I suggest using either litmus or email on acid which displays how your message will look across a range of email clients.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, view the source of the e-mail to see if the e-mail even contains the CSS you expect. If you're using relative paths; this might be the source of the issue. When you visit a page on, say, *//example.com/hello*, a path such as "/css/style.css" will be requested as "//example.com/css/style.css".

An e-mail client has no such luxury; it doesn't have the domainname. You'll have to provide the full path to the CSS, ie "http://example.com/css/style.css".

Answer (score 0):

For this problem what I did is to apply in-line styles and it works fine.